# systemctl says nginx is not running; but nginx _IS_ running

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, systemctl

When I run `sudo systemctl status nginx` on Ubuntu, I'm informed that the service is stopped.

When I run `ps ax | grep nginx`, I see two different PIDs for nginx than above (one master, one worker), both running. And indeed, my web server is working just fine from the browser.

The problem is that I want to update my nginx config and then reload it with something like `sudo systemctl reload nginx`. But this is a production web server and I'm weary to do that before I understand why systemctl thinks nginx is offline (and is tracking an entirely different PID.)

Comment: Kill all nginx processes and restart.

Comment: I really don't want to do that. This is a production server. I'd like to understand how it got in this state in the first place. I've installed vanilla nginx and not done anything to the configuration other than replaced the server_name with mywebsite.com. And I ran certbot to generate an SSL certificate, which auto-updated the config. But every thing else is vanilla straight off the nginx installation.